# AzureDevops Boards - task items not showing, Agile

Tags: azure-devops, task, agile

i have agile process,

in board i can only see User Story-s and Bugs,  Task  work items not visible in boards,

is it possible to show task work items in boards?

Comment: Read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/backlogs-boards-plans?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi Have you got a chance to check out below answer, may i know if it answered your question?

Answer (score 4):

It is by design that Task work items not shown as cards in boards. They are shown as child work items in the User stories cards. This is because they are in different categories of work item.

In Azure devops Agile process. User Stories and Tasks are used to track work, Bugs track code defects, and Epics and Features are used to group work under larger scenarios.

**Epics**, **Features** and **User Stories**, **Bugs**(Configurable) are also backlog items, as illustrated in the below image. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/about-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=scrum-process#work-item-types-wits) for more inforamtion

[image]

And Boards is designed to manage backlog items. Please check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/kanban-overview?view=azure-devops#use-kanban-boards) for more information.

- Implement Kanban methods
- Define work your team is tasked with by defining user stories, product backlog items, or requirements
- Monitor progress and update the status of work items by drag-and-drop to a column
- Add details and estimates to your backlog items
- Quickly define tasks for backlog items
- Add, run, and update inline tests

To display Task work item in User Story Card, Please check out the documents [Customize your Kanban Board checklist items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/set-up-your-backlog?view=azure-devops#customize-your-kanban-board-checklist-items).